# How to display my templated vector of pairs?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Map {
public:
    vector <pair <T, T>> x;
    void emptyMap();
    insertPair(T, T);
    findKey();
    eraseKey();
    void display();
};

template <class T>
Map<T>::insertPair (T key, T val){ // val = value
    x.push_back(make_pair(key, val));
}

template <class T>
void Map<T>::emptyMap () {
    x.clear();
}

template <class T>

void Map<T>::display () {
    for (const auto &i : x){
       cout << i; //error here 
    }
}

int main () {
    Map <int> dx;
    dx.insertPair (1,2);
    dx.display();
}
```

trying to recreate the map container, for study purposes. i keep getting these errors: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMrVE.png)
errors in text: In instantiation of 'int Map::display() [with T = int], required from here (line 41)

error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'const std::pair') (line 34)

Comment: Yes, there is no `<<` operator overload for a `std::pair`, what is so unclear about that? Your `std::pair` has a `first` and a `second`, try using `<<` with them. Your C++ compiler is not going to come up with code to format a `std::pair` entirely on its own, you have to specify how to do that.

Comment: @cae What is the return type of the function display?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that should be void, woops.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i'll try this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik annoyed at myself for not understanding this, but thanks! it works lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overload for ostreaming a `std::pair` by default. Its fairly straight forward to write your own however:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<A,B>& pair){
    os << pair.first << ", " << pair.second; //one possible output format

    return os;
}
```